# Issue on Exporting Shapefile Points to Google Map Longitude & Latitude?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, google-maps-api, web-mercator

Using ArcGIS 10.2 and Some points in Shapefile with BC Albers Coordinate System I am having problem on Getting Points Longitude & Latitude in Google Map Coordinate System. What I have is a CSV file contains the X and Y data in BC Albers Coordinate System. I Followed these steps :

1. I Uploaded The CSV File Data into Map Using File --> Add Data --> Add XY Data...
2. After Getting the points on the Map I Used Define Projection tool to apply BC Albers Coordinate System into the Layer.
3. The I used the Project tool to transfer Projection from BC Albers (PCS_Albers) to  WGS 1984 Web Mercato (auxiliary sphere)
4. Finally I used the Add XY Coordinate tool get the X and Y of the points on the table. the result look like:

[image]

As you can see the **POINT_X** and  **POINT_Y** are different than original **x** and **y** and when I export the map to KML the data are correctly display on Google Map and Google Earth BUT I need to export these data in MySQL database and get the Google Maps Markers from the POINT_X and  POINT_Y which in this case I am getting absolutely wrong location of the points on the Map!
I checked one of points, for example I got

[image: table3.png]

from table and it renders correctly on the map but when I get the same location from What's Here function on Google Map I am getting Totally different number for Lat and Long as:

[image: cap.png]

[image: gmap.png]

Now as I mentioned before I am going to upload my data into MySQL database and use them through Google Map JavaScript API and get them by PHP, so I NEED to have the actual latitude and Longitude  values in ArcGIS.
Can you please let me know how to do this?

Comment: You need to reproject your data using Reproject data management tool (from  BC Alberts to Geographic WGS84) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000007m000000

Comment: @behseini I thought we had this all squared away?!?!

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS, while in an edit session create new columns for X and Y values in float precision data type.

Then open the Field Calculator, update the new X and Y columns with the Geometry >  $x and $y option:

[image]

If in ArcGIS you want to create fields that simply contain the X and Y or your data, no matter what coordinate system your data is currently assigned, you can use the [Calculate Geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000027000000) option in the attribute table.

First create new fields to hold the X and Y data

Then right-click the X and/or Y fields and choose **calculate geometry**

[image]

The dialogue will give you the option to populate the X / Y column with

X Coordinate of Point
Y Coordinate of Point

I think you can cheat your projection by setting the Data Frame projection to WGS 84 / EPSG 4326:

[image]

Comment: Thank Mapbaker I got confused here in ArcGIS! the shape squashed when I used the  WGS 84 but it looks exactly like Google Maps on WGS 1984 Web Mercato (auxiliary sphere)!

Comment: Ok let's put it this way , if I Project the BC Albers to ONLY `WGS 1984` and try the `Add XY Coordinate ` i am getting exactly what i want for database (Same Format Coordinates as Google Map) BUT the shape squashes On the other way if I project the Layer to `WGS 1984 Web Mercato (auxiliary sphere)` shape is exactly identical to Google Map layer BUT when I try to get X and Y the data are different! why is like so?!

Comment: @Behseini To get X and Y you want to re-project your data from BC Albers TO WGS84... so follow the instructions in my last post but use WGS84/EPSG4326 instead, then follow the instructions above... failing that, send me an email mattbaker at gmail dot com